# Record not delete from database after submitting the form

Tags: php, mysql, database

I put all output of forms in a *while* loop but whenever I try to run delete it stops working. My database has one more that is *id*, which is unique. I am trying to delete using the *id* field but no error shows and its also not working. If I put code in the *while* loop it deletes by own and shows messages one by one. How can I get it to delete outside the loop?

```
 <?php
    session_start();
 ?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
    require_once 'login.php';
    $connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
    if (!$connection)
        die("unable to connect to mysqli:" . mysqli_error());

    mysqli_select_db($connection, "dbase1") or die("db not selected" . mysqli_error());

    $sql = " SELECT * FROM tab";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
    <form class="boxed"  style ="border: 4px solid black ; text-align: center; action ="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

    <h1> Message </h1>

    <?php echo "<br>" . "Name:  " . $row["name"] . "<br>" . " Email :  " . $row["email"] . "<br>" . "Phone # " . $row["phone"] . "<br>" . "Message : " . $row["text"] . "<br>"; ?>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="delete" value="delete" style =" background-color: grey;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 70px;
        margin: 15px 0px;
        cursor: pointer;"/>     
    </form> 
<?php 

        }
    }


    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        echo "hry";

        $sql = " DELETE FROM tab WHERE id=" . $row["id"];
        $result = $connection->query($sql);
    }
?>   
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: First thing - please format your code. What you posted is horrible. You have to learn how the form submission works. You create form in a loop, but the form doesn't submit any data except submit button. So how do you know which record to delete? Check this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp improve your code and I'll help.

Comment: sorry i am beginner in php but what you suggest i am stuck do you need me to indent the code?

Comment: is there any other way then while loop to bring multiple database entries with a delete button and yes once again thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you should better format your code, use same quotes for same purpose and not mix `'` vs `"`, use indentation to make code readable. Also try to avoid use of inline styles and istead use classes for styling.

To the functionality itself - you have to put some "identification" of what you want to delete by submission of the form. How will the script know which record do you want to delete if all the forms are same?
Also think about why put the record deletion code to the begining of the script instead of to the end. In your scenario: you click delete, the script will show all records (forms) again and then delete one of them (so it's basicaly showing the roceord which doesn't exist any more). If the record deletion code is in the begining, the record is deleted and then the loop shows what it should.

These all are very basics, so you should study more how HTML & PHP work...

Improved and functional code:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
if (!$connection) {
    die('unable to connect to mysqli:' . mysqli_error());
}
//not neccesary when the db is selected during connection
//mysqli_select_db($connection, 'dbase1') or die('db not selected' . mysqli_error());

// submited form process
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'delete') {

    echo "hry";

    $sql    = 'DELETE FROM tab WHERE id=' . $_POST['id'];
    $result = $connection->query($sql);

}
?>

<html>
<body>
    <?php
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tab';
    $result = $connection->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo '<h1> Message </h1>';
            echo '<br>' . 'Name: ' . $row['name'];
            echo '<br>' . ' Email: ' . $row['email'];
            echo '<br>' . ' Phone # ' . $row['phone'];
            echo '<br>' . ' Message: ' . $row['text'];
            echo '<br>';

            echo '<form class="boxed" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="post" style="...">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $row["id"] . '" />';
            echo '<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="delete" style="..." />';
            echo '</form>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much amazing really really helpful once again thanks :)

Comment: i need some more help i little if you can i am having problem with logout if you never mind i can send here once again i appreciate your effort amazing!

Comment: actually its not logging out i am very bad on php stuff i mean with code indentation if you can help with resolving this it would be great help again

Comment: Not a problem, but you should post new question for another problem. Solving login/logout depends on how it's implemented in your app.

Comment: i posted that do i send you a link here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192146/login-logout-not-working-php-properly